# Manually trigger a build in Travis CI

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, travis-ci

Is there a possibility to manually trigger a build in Travic CI?

In Gitlab for example, you can do it like this:

```
deploy:
  stage: test
  when: manual
  ...
```

Then you manually activate the job from the pipeline.
I don't want my code to run on each commit, so a manual step for activating a build would be useful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I see your point. Only **manual** ways to trigger a build is;

- To visit the Repository page on travis-ci.com > Settings > Trigger Build [1]. You can also add additional configurations from the textbox that will pop up.
- Another option would be(from the command line) triggering an API request manually using Travis CI API v3[2].

[1] https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/web-ui/#trigger-a-custom-build

[2] https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/triggering-builds/